# Are these the stolen gods/idols of Laban in Genesis 35:2?

Tags: genesis, referent-identification, jacob

Genesis 35:2,4 NASB

> <sup>2</sup>So Jacob said to his household and to all who were with him, "Put away the foreign gods which are among you, and purify yourselves and change your garments; ...
>
> <sup>4</sup>So they gave to Jacob all the foreign gods which they had and the rings which were in their ears, and Jacob hid them under the oak which was near Shechem.

There is no mention of worship of foreign gods in Jacobs family in the previous chapters other than Rachel stealing her father's gods (Genesis 31:19).

After disputing with Laban (Genesis 31:36), Jacob tells his household to bring forward all foreign gods.

1. Did Jacob suspect that Laban must have been telling the truth?
2. Are the idols brought forward the ones stolen from Laban?
3. Could the issue of idols have brought about the seemingly untimely death of Rachel?

Comment: And it's also the possible reason why Rachel is barren.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jacob's household had idols](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54554/jacobs-household-had-idols)

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 31:30
New International Version

> Now you have gone off because you longed to return to your father's household. But why did you steal my gods?"

Jacob Wrestles with God
Jacob Meets Esau
Jacob Settles in Shechem
Shechem Defiles Dinah

Genesis 35:2

> So Jacob said to his household and to all who were with him, "Get rid of the foreign gods you have with you, and purify yourselves and change your clothes.

There was a period of months to perhaps more than a year between Laban's accusation to Jacob's command to get rid of the idols.
There were plenty of opportunities for Jacob's people to acquire idols locally in Shechem.

Did Jacob suspect that Laban must have been telling the truth?

No.

> Genesis 31:31 Jacob answered Laban, “I was afraid, because I thought you would take your daughters away from me by force. 32But if you find anyone who has your gods, **that person shall not live**. In the presence of our relatives, see for yourself whether there is anything of yours here with me; and if so, take it.” Now Jacob did not know that Rachel had stolen the gods.
> ...
> 36Jacob was angry and took Laban to task. “What is my crime?” he asked Laban. “How have I wronged you that you hunt me down? 37Now that you have **searched through all my goods**, what have you found that belongs to your household? Put it here in front of your relatives and mine, and let them judge between the two of us.

Jacob's conscience was clear. He was quite sure his people didn't steal anything from Laban.

Are the idols brought forward the ones stolen from Laban?

No. Laban performed a thorough search and didn't find anything. Jacob's people lately interacted locally in Shechem and acquired them. Jacob knew about these and wanted them gone because
Genesis 35:1

> Then God said to Jacob, "Go up to Bethel and settle there, and build an altar there to God, who appeared to you when you were fleeing from your brother Esau."